# Invisible file to tar

Tags: tar

I met the error below while trying to pack a folder.

> tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive

Here is the simple command I did

```
tar -c --file=my_tar_file.tar titi
```

Here is my structure

```
toto/ (current directory)
--toto/
--titi/
----video/
------versions/
--------video (file without extension, 4octets, small text inside)
```

I don't really understand this error, is it possible the file is too small, too deep or invisible by tar ?

It seems to me that if I tar only file or all the folder tree, I'll not get the same result, am I right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there's a known bug with this error, but there's a few things to try

```
tar -cvf my_tar_file.tar ./titi
```

OR

```
tar -cvf my_tar_file.tar -C ./titi
```

OR Possibly add

```
tar -cvf my_tar_file.tar ./titi/*
```